# Pairwise correlation based on effect size values with missing values of some variables

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, meta-analysis

I have data with seven variables and I want to calculate pairwise correlation (also the significance level of each correlation). The data I have is the effect size of a treatment on these seven variables. -ve value shows inhibiting effects and +ve value promoting effects. The higher or lower the value is the higher or lower the inhibiting or promoting effect is on certain variables. Data also contain a large number of missing values, so in pairwise correlation, I want R to ignore the correlation if one or both of the variables missing the value.

Here is a sample dataset

```
set.seed(123)

     # Create the dataset with effect sizes and missing values
mydata <- data.frame(
  Var1 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var2 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var3 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var4 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var5 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var6 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var7 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE)
)

# Set more than 50% missing values in each column
for (col in 1:7) {
  missing_indices <- sample(1:200, size = 101)
  mydata[missing_indices, col] <- NA
}
```

Although I can calculate the correlations that I want using `cor.test()`  with following codes:

```
r <- outer(
  1:ncol(mydata),
  1:ncol(mydata),
  Vectorize(function(x, y) cor.test(mydata[,x], mydata[,y])$estimate)
)
p <- outer(
  1:ncol(mydata),
  1:ncol(mydata),
  Vectorize(function(x, y) cor.test(mydata[, x], mydata[, y])$p.value)
)
```

but my question is that is it worth calculating such correlation based on a single value of an effect size?

Comment: In what sense do you have a single value of effect size? As you describe it, the data is a matrix of 7xN effect sizes, describing the effect size on each variable for each individual, as a result of some common treatment. If you're missing so much data that you only have one individual measured for a variable, you can't do any correlation at all.

Comment: For example, this data is the effect sizes of the effect of a specific treatment on seven variables. Data in each row is from one study (research article). +ve value shows the promoting and -ve value shows the inhibiting effect. Missing values are those when some studies did not check the treatment effect on some variables. For example in one study, treatment promoted (+4.56) variable1 and also variable5 (+2.65), which means that is a positive correlation between two variables, right? I am trying to find a collective correlation between all the available pairs of variables. Is it possible?